# how to position two divs next to each other but still be in center

Tags: html, css

I am really struggling with this and have been at it for quite some time.

I have a background image with a logo and I want a div in the center such that it doesn't block the BEE image in the background.  Working Example here (this is fine as it doesn't block the image): http://jsbin.com/ubanuf/9

However, now I want to add another div right to the left of the red div with some margin in between of about 10pixels. However, when I do this everything moves towards the right and my logo in the background is blocked by the divs. Example here: http://jsbin.com/ubanuf/10

If I remove `margin: 20px auto 0` from `main-controller` then things look decent until I look at the page in `1680 X 1050` resolution. In this resolution everything seems to be shifted towards left. so now there is a huge gap in between where red div stops and the bee image begins. Screen shot here: http://i53.tinypic.com/25qqk4h.png

Why is it that I can't place the yellow div right next to the red div with margin of 10 px between them

My requirements are:

- Red div to be 750 px
- Yellow div to be around 200 px
- both next to each other with about 10 px margin between them
- and bee image should not be blocked

Is this possible to do at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about: http://jsbin.com/ubanuf/12/

Added a wrapping div with margin:auto and a fixed width of both divs and the margin (if you want to increase the margin you need to increase the size of this wrapper aswell)

Comment: this blocks the image in `1280 x 1024` resolution :(

Comment: thats because the red and yellow div have a fixed size and thus overlap the logo on lower resolutions. The requirements you set clash. Either you have a fluid box in the middle that never overlaps the bee (but can get very small) or you have a fixed box that will overlap the bee

Comment: Yeah, I slightly had a clue that those requirements clash but wanted someone with more experience in css to confirm it.  I will redo the image so that I can move the bee image down and put my login etc. in the header. This will eliminate the need of yellow div on the left

Comment: You could try apply http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/ The sliding doors to make it always show

Comment: what does the overflow:hidden do?

Comment: The answer's URL has been "moved or deleted."